# How to enable type hinting for pythonnet imported .NET library?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python.net

The general problem is state in the title. To be more specific.

- I have my own C# .NET project
- I am able to publish it (build DLLs) and import it in Python via [pythonnet](http://pythonnet.github.io/)
- I am able to build a Python package via setuptools - i.e.  "wrapping" the .NET project into distribuable Python package

However, I am unable to add type hinting for .NET commands and classes to the Python package.

What did I try:

- I generated python stubs files for my .NET project using https://github.com/mcneel/pythonstubs It works very well
- I added the generated stubs folder into my Python package

But my editor (PyCharm) is unable to find the stubs folder in my package. I wonder if anyone tried to resolve similar task. Any help or hint is appreciated.